# PHP doesn't exit for loop or MySql gets too many requests in some way

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The piece of code is quite simple. I'm trying to insert in a table every sentence contained in the variable $str separated by a '@'. The problem is that it doesn't stop to the end of the array in the for loop and keeps creating new blank rows.

```
    <?php
    require_once("database/functions.php");

    $str = "text@text@text...";

    $arr = explode('@', $str);
    var_dump($arr);

    global $ConnectionClass;
    $ConnectionClass->Connect();

    for($i = 0; i < count($arr); $i++){
        $check = $ConnectionClass->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO flow VALUES('', '$arr[$i]', '', '', '', '')");
        if(!$check) die("Impossibile dialogare con il Database.");
    }

    $ConnectionClass->Close();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missnamed your $i variable in the for declaration :

do

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
```

instead of

```
for($i = 0; i < count($arr); $i++){
```

Comment: Thank you. I had it in front of my face all the time but I needed you help.

Answer (score 0):

add $i variable in the for loop condition

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
        $check = $ConnectionClass->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO flow VALUES('', '$arr[$i]', '', '', '', '')");
        if(!$check) die("Impossibile dialogare con il Database.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you loop variable, you mis-spelled it. It must be $i.
It is a usually overseen mistake.